# Native screen resolution not available after fresh install

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, resolution

After fresh install of ubuntu 12.10 I've got a wrong resolution: 1920x1080 instead of 1920x1200.

And neither default drivers, nor nvidia's can recognize my 1920x1200 resolution.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What video driver are you using?  The NVIDIA one or the free one?

Comment: nvidia one, but i had the same results with free one (default one)

Comment: And what monitor?

Comment: nec multisync ex231wp

Comment: hm.. looked for specs, looks like this is the native resolution.. is this case closed? :)

Comment: The [specs](http://www.necdisplay.com/p/desktop-monitors/ex231wp-bk) of your monitor indeed list 1920x1080 as native, so the question seems to be invalid. What are you seeing to what makes you think it's not a native resoltion? E.g. unused part of the screen.